# How to prevent it from accepting one letter with one space each side of it (one letter word)?

Tags: regex

Need Regex

^(?:\d{1,3}\h+)?\D\S*(?:\h+\S+){0,3}$
https://regex101.com/r/t2HCLm/1
It is working fine for me.
now I want to modify it

How to prevent it from accepting one letter with one space each side of it (one letter word)? I meant that each word's letter limit should more than 1 letter. example: This is a School=false This is the School=true

```
This is a School=false 
This is the School=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
^(?:\d{1,3}\h+)?[^\d\s]\S+(?:\h+\S{2,}){0,3}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pIvBk8/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - string start
- `(?:\d{1,3}\h+)?` - an optional sequence of one, two or three digits followed with one or more horizontal whitespaces
- `[^\d\s]` - a char other than a digit and whitespace
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespaces
- `(?:\h+\S{2,}){0,3}` - zero to three sequences of one or more horizontal whitespaces and then two or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - string end.